# Generate a list that is garanteed to have a 7 in it

Tags: list, haskell, quickcheck

How do I do this? I want something with the structure `sevenList :: Gen [Integer]` that generates a list and that is guaranteed to always include at least one 7.

I know that if I wanted to generate a list of size n, I could do something like this:

```
listOfLength n gen = sequence [ gen | i <- [1..n] ]
```

But this is not sufficient because if I for example generate a list of length 10 and a 7 is not generated I have to continue, but at the moment it wont.

Comment: You can generate an index, split at that index, and inject a seven at that place.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That may work, did not think about that.

Comment: Minor point: keep in mind that, mathematically speaking, a "random list" is ambiguous, and might refer to _any_ distribution over the set of all lists. There are many options here. Usually, one uses a distribution that makes the length to be distributed geometrically. Similarly, note that there are many distributions for "random lists containing at least one 7".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can decide to generate two lists, and then construct a list where we append the lists with a seven sandwiched between them.

For instance:

```
genSevenList :: Gen [Integer]
genSevenList = do
    la <- arbitrary
    lb <- arbitrary
    return $ la ++ 7 : lb
```

The first two statements thus generate two arbitrary `[Integer]` lists, and then we `return $ la ++ 7 : lb`. We thus prepend `lb` with `7`, and append this to `la`.

You can also generate one arbitrary list, split it at a random index and then join these parts together as described above. For instance:

```
genSevenList :: Gen [Integer]
genSevenList = do
    l <- arbitrary
    k <- choose (0,length l)
    let (la,lb) = splitAt k l
    return $ la ++ 7 : lb
```

Although both are capable of generating all possible lists, like @leftroundabout says, it is more likely that the second implementation will come up with shorter lists, since the odds that both `aribtrary` calls will generate a short list (or an empty list) is not that large.

Comment: The main difference between the two approaches is that, with two separate `arbitrary` lists, it is very unlikely that both will be empty, i.e. the case `[7]` may not happen as often as necessary. Thus, generating one list and injecting a seven somewhere is probably better for coverage testing.